# Using Minecraft Rigs In Blender

Tags: blender

It is my third day using Blender. I make models with minecraft. It was working perfectly until suddenly when I tried to render my image, it made the items gray. How do I made it work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs somewhere else, also lacks detail

Answer (score 0):

The light grey result means you have no material setup (or just have the default material). I expect you want to add and [image texture](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/types/image.html) to your model.

If you have done some texture painting, you still need to setup the image texture information for the material for it to be used during render.

You may also need to [uv unwrap](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/mapping/uv/unwrapping.html) your model for the image to work right.